# omnifaces generic enum converter values order

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I am using omnifaces 1.6.2 on a project. A have an enum with values like this:

AC, AL, AP, AM, BA

But when the values are shown in a selectonemenu they are always in a different order.
Is there a way to show these values always in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the [`omnifaces.GenericEnumConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter), but to the [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants). This issue was already reported as [issue 260](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=260) and fixed in 1.7 snapshot. If you upgrade to 1.7 snapshot, then this problem should go away. The final 1.7 release is expected around december.

Comment: I upgraded and a strange thing happened. The html that was rendered was correct. But, I can't click on the item, or better, when I click on it, the list of values is not shown.

Comment: Works for me. Note: I assume standard JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>`. If you're using a 3rd party component library, check for JS errors in the console.

Comment: It is this component. It has something to do with col-md-* class from bootstrap 3. If I remove the class from the component or the div surrounding it, it works...

Comment: The new problem seems to be not related. Or are you implying that this part works fine when OmniFaces 1.6.x is used? (although the items are in wrong order)

Comment: It is a css problem, for sure. Not omnifaces.